# How to stop Magento 2 from logging into var/debug/db.log

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento 2 site which crashes everytime `db.log` file gets full. All I need to do to restore the site is to delete `db.log` file in `var/debug/` folder and make the folder writable.

How do I tell Magento not to log into this file again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the below command to disable SQL query logging:

```
bin/magento dev:query-log:disable
```

Flush the Cache

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/enable-logging.html?lang=en

Comment: The command is 100% correct, my question would be: why it was enabled? By DEFAULT it is Disabled!

I guess you might also notice slight Performance Improvement after running bin/magento dev:query-log:disable. Seems to me a Dev Enabled it and forget to Disable it... Which is not something that should be done, especially for Production Environments...

Comment: @PiotrSiejczuk Yes you are right. It is off by default but I can remember that during troubleshooting of  customer login problem on the site, we tried different things which includes turning on sql logging.

Comment: @KunsalAjay: In case of such Performance / Troubleshooting situations I would suggest to use (even in trail option) tools like: NewRelic and/or Blackfire.io